# Visual Studio Online move PBI and tasks from one project to another

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Online I have created a project A with PBI's that has many tasks inside them. 
I have now created a new project B and would like to move/copy/migrate the PBI's and tasks from project A to this project B. 
How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 2020 now, and the answer, with Azure DevOps is yes, you most definitely can.
See Azure boards documentation's "[move work items, change work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops#move-a-work-item-to-another-project)"

Comment: Thanks, @Mohammad S., for making this the "new" correct answer. I didn't expect it. Maybe this is happening around S.O., but I see too many questions where the 5th or 10th or nth answer is the new correct answer, because things change over time. So yea, thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this quite easily using the Excel integration feature.

1. In Project A, create a query that lists all your work items.
2. Open Microsoft Excel, go the TEAM tab.
3. Click 'New List', select your project, select 'Query List', select
   the query you just created.
4. In the Work Items tab select the 'Choose Columns' button and select
   all the columns you want to migrate.
5. Open another Excel Spreadsheet and create a 'New List'. This time
   connect to Project B and select the 'Input List'.
6. Copy and paste all the work items from Project A list to the Project
   B list (excluding the Id column).
7. Click Publish.

Comment: I was able to do just about everything I needed to in this method.  You can choose additional columns once you select your query if all the columns you want to update are not initially visible.

Comment: This method doesn't copy images.

Answer (score 3):

Using Excel won't let you copy a lot of stuff, particularly attachments.

A (slightly) better approach would be to use the OData interface at https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/ to read work items and all their related data from project A, then insert into project B.

As of today though, the API is also quite limited (e.g. doesn't allow to create links between work items).