# Can a TFS Product Backlog Item be moved to a new project?

Tags: tfs

I have a PBI in TFS under ProjectA with an iteration and area value filled in. Is it possible to move this PBI to ProjectB without creating a new PBI?

I am not seeing a way in the Visual Studio UI to do this. If I try to manually type in the area path of ProjectB, Visual Studio says that the path cannot be found.

I am using Team Foundation Server 2013 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Work items cannot be moved between team projects.

The reason is simple: The process template of the team project defines the work items. Team projects can have different templates. What if you tried to move a work item from a team project using a Scrum template to one using a CMMI template?

Answer (score 2):

I would go a little deeper and say that if you need this feature then you should not have two Team Projects in the first place.

http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project/

The term that I use is:

"If you have artifacts that interact, with artifacts defined as people, code, or work items, then they should be in a single Team Project"

http://nakedalm.com/creating-nested-teams-visual-studio-alm/

Using a single Team Project can give you many more capabilities at the backlog/ work tracking perspective. Like the nested teams described above.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: This does not work for TFS2017 and forwards.

Yes, see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1018002/Yes-You-Can-Move-TFS-WorkItems-Between-Projects for a downloadable utility, source and a more detailed explaination.

It is a backdoor, SQL Manager approach, not supported by Microsoft, but it works for me.  Here is the SQL:

```
UPDATE [Tfs_xxx].[dbo].[WorkItemsAre] SET AreaID=@AreaID,IterationID=@IterationID WHERE ID=@WorkItemID
UPDATE [Tfs_xxx].[dbo].[WorkItemsLatest] SET AreaID=@AreaID,IterationID=@IterationID WHERE ID=@WorkItemID
UPDATE [Tfs_xxx].[dbo].[WorkItemsWere] SET AreaID=@AreaID,IterationID=@IterationID WHERE ID=@WorkItemID
```

With the Tfs_xxx being replaced with Tfs_<your collection database name>.

Essentially, the project is inherited from the Area and the Iteration.  Changing these from the current project to the target project causes the workitem to "move" to the target project.  Additional rough edges are that the assignment pool or the workflow states might not align and have to be edited mannually in the UI to get the workitem back in the flow of the target project.

Comment: Direct manipulations to the SQL database of TFS are not supported. You will risk that your TFS instance becomes unstable. You also run the risk that we as Microsoft will not support you to fix the issue once you have done direct SQL manipulations.

We have had multiple incidents from customers who have tried this, and they broke their warehouse sync of TFS. 

Ewald Hofman
TFS Program Manager

Comment: @EwaldHofman, when can we expect a supported solution from Microsoft?

Comment: We have a Work Item move available in VSTS, but unfortunately we are unable to ship that to on-prem because the TFS warehouse doesn't support it. We are looking at options how we can support it.

We don't have an ETA yet.

Comment: @EwaldHofman, found this gem in the referenced article's comments "The Microsoft 'Agile' Methodology: 1) Software missing useful features that many customers could use for many years. 2) Customers unwisely try to workaround because of lack of interest in MS helping their customers.  3) Customers messing up their TFS databases. 4) MS spends more time and work telling customers what not to do to workaround their software's limitations and missing, useful features than doing something to resolve the issue. 5)Software continues missing useful features ...<b><i>Thanks Microsoft!</i></b>

Comment: @EwaldHofman Do you have any new information about that topic moving PBIs from one Team Project to another Team Project in another Team collection? With Azure DevOps Server 2019 it's possible to move PBIs, Tasks, etc. to another project in same Team collection, but is it possible to move it to a project in another Team Collection?

Comment: @ChW, you will probably have to take a migration approach.  That is copy from one collection into the other.  You will get the work item in the new collection, but not the history.

Answer (score 0):

[See my related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62905244/5818960).
Though not applicable to TFS on-premise, one can now [do this with Azure Boards in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops#move-a-work-item-to-another-project).